Unprecedented reviewing times for Google Play Android apps
I am posting this because I really don't know what to do. Today is the 7th (7th!) day since I submitted average app updates for review for a family of apps that I work on. They are still in review. I contacted support twice, but they wash their hands. I have users and customers waiting for these updates, due to new features and fixing of critical bugs. I suppose I am not the only one. Is there a way this can be escalated? Is this what I have to expect from now on? Note they are not new apps: they have been is the play store for years.
Thanks.
I wrote twice to support. They wash their hands and redirect me to support page.

How is it going since then?

I have faced the same situation twice recently. Ordinally the review takes only a few hours but it kept showing the in review status for over a day.
I thought there was something wrong on the Google end and then decided to cancel the submission and re-submit the same app. It was successful. The review passed in a few hours as usual.
Go to Publishing overview > Click the arrow icon on the version being in review > Discard release.
Give it a shot. I hope it works for you as well.

My company is facing the same thing.  We were in review for over 20 days.  I emailed the support group and they opened a ticket; however, we never got any information back on why it was held up.  I emailed back and forth with the support group multiple times, and their underlying reply was "we appreciate your patients." Thinking my build hit a bug on Google's end, I tried to clean up the items in review and submit it back, but now we are back in an extended review.
For what it is worth, we are a medical app.  I know Apple started to crack down on medical apps this year and we faced a very long review cycle with them as well.  On the positive note with Apple, they worked with us to find solutions for critical fixes.  I have no contacts at Google, so we are waiting for any update.
